# jquery getscript ignore my path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a problem with jquery.getScript

I load my code with

```
$.getScript("assets/global/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js?" + Math.random())
```

but in the browser's console i have this error

```
http://localhost:53968/UI/WebPages/jquery.dataTables.min.js.map 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the structure of pages and script

/UI/WebPages/calling_pages.aspx
/UI/WebPages/assets/global/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

So if I place a direct

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/global/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
```

everything is working, but I need to test if the js is loaded to prevent multiple loading

Comment: Remove the `//#sourceMappingURL` on your js file?

Comment: thank you this is working. for now i think i use this way but i have to fix this problem in my code because plugin is not mine and maybe i can have this problem in the future. thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/):

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
.done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

I would change the query param from

```
"...jquery.dataTables.min.js?" + Math.random()
```

to

```
"...jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=1.10.2"
```

because you aren't changing the file either there comes an update, isn't it. I think it the best value for renewing the browsers cache. But beware, in the docs is a hint for enable caching:

```
// By default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false.
// This appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL
// to ensure that the browser downloads the script each time it
// is requested. You can override this feature by setting the cache
// property globally using $.ajaxSetup():

$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
});
```